# Obtaining connection to database in JBoss?

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets, jboss

This is my jboss/deploy/postgres-ds.xml file. The connection url, username and password is given here. How do I obtain a connection to this database in my servlet.

```
<local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>PostgresDS</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</connection-url>
        <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
        <password>qwerty</password>
            <!-- sql to call when connection is created
            <new-connection-sql>some arbitrary sql</new-connection-sql>
            -->

            <!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool 
            <check-valid-connection-sql>some arbitrary sql</check-valid-connection-sql>
            -->

          <!-- corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml (optional) -->

      </local-tx-datasource>
```

Should I obtain the connection like this in every servlet :

```
Connection conn =null; // Create connection object
        String database = "postgres"; // Name of database
        String user = "postgres"; //
             String password = "qwerty";
             String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/" + database;
ResultSet rs = null;
             ResultSetMetaData rsm = null;  
 try{
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
//.newInstance()
} catch(Exception e) 
   {
System.err.println(e);
}

try{
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

}catch(SQLException se) 
{
System.err.println(se);
}
```

If this has to be done everytime, then why give the url, username and password in the postgres-ds.xml file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use DataSource to get Connection like

```
javax.naming.Context ic = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
javax.naming.Context ctx = (javax.naming.Context) ic.lookup("java:");
javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("PostgresDS");
java.sql.Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: "java.sql.Connection con = ds.getConnection();". For each call to this function, a different connection object is returned?

Comment: From the system's perspective, "No: not necessarily".  Another advantage of using the DS over a JDBC connection is that using the DS allows you to take advantage of the app server's connection pooling.

Comment: @Satya "javax.naming.Context ctx = (javax.naming.Context) ic.lookup("java:");" Where does this line do the lookup?. The third line does a lookup in PostGres-ds.xml file. Right?

Comment: 1. gets initialContext in naming tree 2. gets the java branch by looking up "java:" in initial context 3. gets the Datasource by  looking up "postgresDS" in the branches of "java:"

Comment: @Satya Can you specify the files in which these lookups are done? For example Postgre-ds.xml

Comment: Suraj once Postgres-ds.xml is deployed it binds PostgresDS in JNDI tree , which is already up and running in JBOSS. You can try having a look at the same in jmx-console at http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/, so in essence the binding goes like IC->java:->PostgresDS , now here what you have defined is PostgresDS , rest all are already done by JBOSS and JNDI

Answer (score 2):

No - using a "data source" in a J2EE app (like a JBoss-based app) and opening a standard JDBC connection (as you'd do in a simple Java application) are more or less mutually exclusive.

Your app would generally do one or the other.  In your case, use the data source.

Here's a great snippet that illustrates *both* approaches: using a JNDI datasource, and opening a JDBC connection directly:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=127

```
/** Uses JNDI and Datasource (preferred style).   */
static Connection getJNDIConnection(){
String DATASOURCE_CONTEXT = "java:comp/env/jdbc/blah";

Connection result = null;
try {
  Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
  if ( initialContext == null){
    log("JNDI problem. Cannot get InitialContext.");
  }
  DataSource datasource = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCE_CONTEXT);
  if (datasource != null) {
    result = datasource.getConnection();
  }
  else {
    log("Failed to lookup datasource.");
  }
}
catch ( NamingException ex ) {
  log("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
}
catch(SQLException ex){
  log("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with JBoss, it is advisable to take advantage of the included EE APIs like [**JPA**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.htm).

Thus you would not need to retype your connection information anywhere. Just let the container inject an `EntityManager` into your servlet (provided you are using EE 6 with [**CDI**](http://seamframework.org/Weld)) or create something like a [**DAO**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) (without EE6).

You might want to take a look at [**this JPA example**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html) using Hibernate on JBoss.